# Python websockets send to client and keep connection alive

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm using python websockets: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/

They have a simple client/server example, where the server echoes the client's input back once. The code looks like this:

Client side:

```
# WS client example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(
            'ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        print(f"> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Server side:

```
# WS server example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I want to adapt just the server side only, so that it does the following upon a socket connection:

1. Send an acknowledgement message to the client. e.g. `Hello Client! Please wait for your data.`
2. Keep the connection alive.
3. Process some data that takes some time.
4. After the data has completed processing, notify the client on the existing websocket connection. e.g. `Your data is here!`

The python websockets documentation doesn't have a code sample which does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably your function that processes the data is blocking, otherwise you'd simply `await` it inside the coroutine. The straightforward approach is to use `run_in_executor` to run it in another thread, and `await` it in your handler coroutine:

```
async def hello(websocket, path):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await websocket.send("Hello Client! Please wait for your data.")
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, get_data)
    await websocket.send("Your data is here!")
    await websocket.send(data)

def get_data():
    # something that takes a long time to calculate
    x = 19134702400093278081449423917**300000 % 256
    return bytes([x])
```

Answer (score 11):

To keep the connection open do not terminate the handler after processing the first message. For example, you can have an endless-loop that will keep processing the incoming messages until the connection is closed by the client:

```
async def hello(websocket, path):
    while True:
        try:
            name = await websocket.recv()
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print(f"Terminated")
            break

        print(f"< {name}")
        greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

        await websocket.send(greeting)
        print(f"> {greeting}")
```

In the `async` fun you can then `await` any long running operation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53335373/2202174).

You will however need to adapt both server and client side in the similar way. Your client also terminates after receiving the first message.

Comment: Can you please tell how to write the same `hello` function for client?